# How to pin message extension to the compose box for a group of users in Microsoft Teams

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a tenant with 10,000 users and we have an app that acts as a message extension and tab both, that we want to add for all users.  I can see how to pin a bot to the sidebar, but how do I pin a message extension for all my users.

[image]

---

---

**Edit:**
As per the [Microsoft Schema Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema), I am not allowed to add **Scope** for **ComposeExtenion** and **personal** under **configurableTabs** scope.

[image]

Comment: Suggest to Improve the title to clarify -> 
How to pin message extension to the compose box for a group of users in Microsoft Teams

Comment: @Gaurav Gupta Config Tabs is only supported for channel level or group chat, if you want to add tab for personal level you can use static tab. For compose extensions there is no need specify scopes as you can use in personal, team level by default.

Comment: Could you please go through below document.If its helped you in any way. [Manage app setup policies in Microsoft Teams - Microsoft Teams | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/microsoftteams/teams-app-setup-policies?WT.mc_id=TeamsAdminCenterCSH#pin-apps)

Answer (score 2):

using the Teams App Setup Policies there are two options to 'push' Teams Apps to groups of users:

- Install Apps
- Pin Apps

**Pinning** by design uses a Personal scope for a Tab or Bot, and only works if the App has a personal scope

**Installing** should work for any teams apps that can be installed ( respecting other settings and App Permission Policies)

**Note:** There is a know caveat for message extensions:
When a Tenant Admin pre-installs the app via a TAC App Setup Policy , or Graph :

- the app only shows in the overflow tray
- **and does not get pre-pinned directly to the compose box.**

There is work planned to address this in the 2nd half of CY21

[image]

Comment: I have made an edit to the manifest and gave some issues - update the issue above.